# PHP fwrite error

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm stuck. Been trying to fix this. The example is almost identical to the teachers... I don't get it.... The html is [here](http://www.deltacst.net/php06/Lab5/Lab5.html). Its simple setup for a schedule. It won't write to the file correctly. Help?

EDIT: It won't write the variables to the file. I can get it to write text, just not the variables. Hope that clarifies.

```
<?php

    /* Create folder for data */
    if (is_dir('schedule'))
    chdir('schedule');
    else
    {mkdir('schedule');
     chdir ('schedule');}

    /* Variable Declaration */
    /* Employee 1 */
    $sunStart1=$_POST['sunStart1'];
    $sunEnd1=$_POST['sunEnd1'];
    $monStart1=$_POST['monStart1'];
    $monEnd1=$_POST['monEnd1'];
    $tuesStart1=$_POST['tuesStart1'];
    $tuesEnd1=$_POST['tuesEnd1'];
    $wedStart1=$_POST['wedStart1'];
    $wedEnd1=$_POST['wedEnd1'];
    $thurStart1=$_POST['thurStart1'];
    $thurEnd1=$_POST['thurEnd1'];
    $friStart1=$_POST['friStart1'];
    $friEnd1=$_POST['friEnd1'];
    $satStart1=$_POST['satStart1'];
    $satEnd1=$_POST['satEnd1'];

    /* Employee 2 */
    $sunStart2=$_POST['sunStart2'];
    $sunEnd2=$_POST['sunEnd2'];
    $monStart2=$_POST['monStart2'];
    $monEnd2=$_POST['monEnd2'];
    $tuesStart2=$_POST['tuesStart2'];
    $tuesEnd2=$_POST['tuesEnd2'];
    $wedStart2=$_POST['wedStart2'];
    $wedEnd2=$_POST['wedEnd2'];
    $thurStart2=$_POST['thurStart2'];
    $thurEnd2=$_POST['thurEnd2'];
    $friStart2=$_POST['friStart2'];
    $friEnd2=$_POST['friEnd2'];
    $satStart2=$_POST['satStart2'];
    $satEnd2=$_POST['satEnd2'];

    /* Make data file */
    $schedule = fopen('schedule.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($schedule, "$sunStart1\n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$sunEnd1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$monStart1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$monEnd1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$tuesStart1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$tuesEnd1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$wedStart1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$wedEnd1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$thurStart1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$thurEnd1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$friStart1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$friEnd1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$satStart1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$satEnd1 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$sunStart2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$sunEnd2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$monStart2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$monEnd2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$tuesStart2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$tuesEnd2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$wedStart2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$wedEnd2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$thurStart2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$thurEnd2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$friStart2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$friEnd2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$satStart2 \n");
    fwrite($schedule, "$satEnd2 \n");
    fclose ($schedule);
  ?>
```

Comment: "It won't write to the file correctly" - Give us a clue?? What is the expected result and what are you getting?

Comment: Why cant you use a control array? So you dont have to specifically name each control.

Comment: It doesn't want to write the variables to the file.

Comment: @craig1231 I honestly don't know what that is. I'm beginning php. This is an assignment for an "Intro to PHP" course.

Comment: As an aside, the question presumably originally contained your <form> syntax. However now that it has been edited to remove that, new readers can't follow the question. It is usually better to add extra info at the bottom of your question, or to cross things out explicitly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forms method is not syntaxed correctly...

You have

```
<form action="lab5.php" method"POST">
```

It should be

```
<form action="lab5.php" method="POST">
```

Plus your form structure is also not correct...

I would place the `<form>` before the `<table>` and subsequenctly end `</form>` after `</table>`

Comment: Everytime. Everytime. Its always something stupid... Thank you so much. If I may ask, did you just skim it to find that? or did you use some sort of scanner to detect errors?

Comment: Skimmed it, ive been programming for too long ;) However you could use the http://validator.w3.org/ to validate your HTML code ;)

Comment: Well thanks for your help. I need to learn to look over stuff like this. I'll check as answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Do you have any program suggestions. I used to use HTML kit because it was free and I'm a poor college student lol.

Comment: I would recommend Netbeans, thats free ;)

Comment: Haha @sakfa, got there before me!